# Pass boolean value by checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

I would like to pass my bool value by checkbox.

Here's my property

```
  public bool MyBooleanValue{ get; set; } = true;
```

and here;s my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@nameof(Model.MyBooleanValue)" name="my-boolean" value="1" class="" checked="checked" />

<label for="@nameof(Model.MyBooleanValue)">some text</label>

<input type="hidden" name="my-boolean" value="true" />
```

In default I would like to have checked field. What's wrong with this code ?
I use ASP.NET MVC 5.
I always get the same value

Comment: Just use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyBooleanValue)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the MVC helper:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyBooleanValue)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBooleanValue)
```

You can check the *FormCollection* if the *MyBooleanValue* is *true* or *false*, depending on the checkbox state.

---

Alternatively use the simple html code:

```
<label for="MyBooleanValue">Some label text</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="MyBooleanValue" name="MyBooleanValue" checked="checked" value="Some value you want to pass if checked">
```

If the checkbox is checked the *value* will be passed in the form. Otherwise, the *FormCollection* does not contain this value.